# Using Enums in Entity Framework Where Clause

Tags: linq, entity-framework, enums, lambda

So here is what I have for my enum. Really basic. The enum does NOT have a corresponding database table. Rather, whenever a class has a MyEnum property, the database has an int column. That all works fine.

```
public enum MyEnum : int
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

This is my class, it has its own table in the database.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public long MyClassID { get; set; }
    public MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

So when I go to pull out a MyClass object, the MyEnum property is set to its corresponding int value, hooray. My problem is when I try to write a query that uses the MyEnum property, I get an error.

```
public List<MyClass> FindAllOfEnum(MyEnum myEnum)
{
    using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
    {
        return db.MyClasses.Where(x => x.MyEnum == myEnum);
    }
}

// ERROR:
// The specified type member 'MyEnum' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

So I tried writing this Value extension method, but I realized that would only allow me to take out the MyEnum reference on the right-hand side of the comparison, since I can't put the function actually in the lambda expression. What do?

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int Value(this MyEnum myEnum)
    {
        return (int)myEnum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the search facility before you post. There are plenty of questions asking this.

Comment: Well then feel free to provide a link along with your snide comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is **not supported** until next major version of EF (.NET 4.5). Until .NET 4.5 you must pass int to your queries (conversion must be done outside of your query). The best workaround is [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150610020516/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/05/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Just cast to begin with:

```
   public List<MyClass> FindAllOfEnum(MyEnum myEnum) 
   { 
      using (DbContext db = new DbContext()) 
      { 
         return db.MyClasses.Where(x => x.MyEnum == (int)myEnum); 
       } 
   }
```

Comment: Nope, this would result in the same error I am getting: The specified type member 'MyEnum' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Edit: Actually, I get "Operator '=='

Comment: Edit: Actually, I get "Operator '=='cannot be applied to operands of type 'MyEnum' and 'int'". And if I use Object.Equals, then I get the above error.

Comment: Right, what I intended there was to compare against the actual column:  return db.MyClasses.Where(x => x.mycolumn == (int)myEnum);

Comment: Okay, thanks. That is what I have right now, I was hoping I didn't have to publicly expose the integer value though, alas.

Comment: brilliant bros  :)